# Command for login history in Strawberry Perl in Windows

Tags: perl

I am getting error i.e last is not recognized as a internal or external in cmd prompt

What I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $d=system("last");
print $d;
```

Comment: What error do you get? Does `last` work when run from the shell (without Perl)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `last` command under windows, you'll have to use something like [wmic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx), `net user` or similar, depending on what info you need/want.

Comment: Other options: `Win32::EventLog` to read  Audit Logon events. Currently logged user, the `quser` command.